# How to find all classes in a package using reflection in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to find all `kotlin` classes in a given package?

I also need only annotated classes but it's not a big deal. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kotlin on the JVM suffers the same issue as Java in this regard due to the implementation of class loaders.

> *Class loaders are not required to tell the VM which classes it can provide, instead they are just handed requests for classes, and have to return a class or throw an exception.*

Source and more information: [`Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520328)

To summarize the linked thread, there are a number of solutions that allow you to inspect your current class path.

- The [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library is pretty straight forward and has a lot of additional functionality like getting all subtypes of a class, **get all types/members annotated with some annotation, optionally with annotation parameters matching**, etc.
- [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has [`ClassPath`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html), which returns [`ClassInfo`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.ClassInfo.html) POJO's - not enough for your use case, but useful to know as Guava is available almost everywhere.
- Write your own by querying classloader resources and code sources. Would not suggest this route unless you absolutely cannot add library dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of querying classloader resources, adapted from https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077477/java-tip-113--identify-subclasses-at-runtime.html

Requires Java 8 or higher.

```
// Call this function using something like:
//     findClasses("com.mypackage.mysubpackage")
// Modified from https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077477/java-tip-113--identify-subclasses-at-runtime.html
fun findClasses(pckgname: String) {
    // Translate the package name into an absolute path
    var name = pckgname
    if (!name.startsWith("/")) {
        name = "/$name"
    }
    name = name.replace('.', '/')

    // Get a File object for the package
    val url: URL = Launcher::class.java.getResource(name)
    val directory = File(url.getFile())

    println("Finding classes:")
    if (directory.exists()) {
        // Get the list of the files contained in the package
        directory.walk()
            .filter { f -> f.isFile() && f.name.contains('$') == false && f.name.endsWith(".class") }
            .forEach {
                val fullyQualifiedClassName = pckgname +
                    it.canonicalPath.removePrefix(directory.canonicalPath)
                    .dropLast(6) // remove .class
                    .replace('/', '.')
                try {
                    // Try to create an instance of the object
                    val o = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
                    if (o is MyInterfaceOrClass) {
                        println(fullyQualifiedClassName)
                        // Optionally, make a function call here: o.myFunction()
                    }
                } catch (cnfex: ClassNotFoundException) {
                    System.err.println(cnfex)
                } catch (iex: InstantiationException) {
                    // We try to instantiate an interface
                    // or an object that does not have a
                    // default constructor
                } catch (iaex: IllegalAccessException) {
                    // The class is not public
                }
            }
    }
}
```